# Malayalam font not supporting in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, fonts

I am building a WordPress website for that content has been already given but while using that content it will display like

```
am\-hn-I-X-bpsS kv]-μ-am-]n-\nIÄ
```

How can I add these type of fonts into WordPress is there any plugins available

Comment: css il fonts import cheythu nokkiyo?

Comment: oru ttf font add cheythu, ennittum rakshayilla

Comment: Answer is fetched from official wordpress forum

Comment: type cheyth idan kazhiyunnund but contentil ninnu copy cheyth idumbol work aakunnilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to convert the current text to Unicode for that I used the website [Unicode convertor](http://lsgkerala.gov.in/unicode/Default.aspx)

`am\-hn-I-X-bpsS kv]-μ-am-]n-\nIÄ` = `മാനവികതയുടെ സ്പന്ദമാപിനികള്‍`

Using this the problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

– use UTF-8 (Unicode) charset

– make a test post; type it directly from your computer’s Unicode Malayalam keyboard

-publish the test post and it should be visible. Try it.

Comment: It may because both are of different font family.

Comment: If you copy a text typed in karthika and copy it to someother font, it may not work.

Comment: so athinte corresponding font file include cheyyanam.
aa font systethil install cheythillenkil, clipboardil format maarippkum

Comment: do you get as expected?

Comment: no, finally I got the site for converting it into Unicode. Using that I have solved the problem